# Search function in c programming

Tags: c, search, struct, structure, file-handling

I am trying to create a program that saves a list into a text file then accesses this list to search for name using id, then display the name, id and information of that person.

There are a lot of faults in my program but i do not understand why the search function does not search for the name in the text file.

Even if the name or id is in the text file, the search always displays, "record could not be found".

Please help me. I want to save the values in the structure and use them from the structure.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct VisitorData{
char *SrNo;
char *ticketNo;
char *Name;
char *ID;
};

struct ticket {
struct VisitorData visitor;
struct ticket *nextPtr;
}ticket1;

// ticket1* start = NULL;

int totalVisitors = 0;

char *my_itoa(int num, char *str)
{
        if(str == NULL)
        {
                return NULL;
        }
        sprintf(str, "%d", num);
        return str;
}

void addVisitor()
{
    system("cls");
    totalVisitors++;
    int TotalVisitors = totalVisitors;

    char fullName[30];
    char ID[20];
    // char serialNumber[2];
    char yesOrNo[2];


    FILE *fp = NULL;

    printf("\nYou have chosen to add a new visitor.");

    // serialNumber[0] = TotalVisitors;

     if ((fp = fopen("Tickets.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            fp = fopen("Tickets.txt", "w");
            fprintf(fp, "Total Visitors: \n");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            fp = fopen("Tickets.txt", "r+");
            fseek(fp, 15, SEEK_SET);
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &TotalVisitors);
            rewind(fp);
            fseek(fp, 15, SEEK_SET);
            fprintf(fp, "%d", TotalVisitors);
            fclose(fp);
        }


    fp = fopen("Tickets.txt", "a+");
    printf("\nEnter your Full name: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    // gets(fullName);
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", fullName);

    char underScore = '_';

    // replace space with underscore in a loop
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(fullName); i++){
        if(fullName[i] == ' ')
            fullName[i] = underScore;
    }

    printf("Your name: ");
    puts(fullName);

    fprintf(fp, "%d ", TotalVisitors);

    printf("\nAre you a Local? [Y/N]: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf(" %s", &yesOrNo);
    // gets(yesOrNo);


    int fullNameLength = strlen(fullName);
    char spaceToAdd = " ";
    char ticketNoChar[20];
    int characterRep[20];

    // adding spaces if full name length is less than 6
    if(fullNameLength < 6){
        while(fullNameLength <6){
            sprintf(fullName,"%s%s", spaceToAdd, fullName);
            fullNameLength = strlen(fullName);
        }
    }

    int ticketNo[20] = {}, i=0, j;
    while(i!=5) {
        ticketNo[i]=fullName[i]; i++;
    }
    printf("Your ticket number: ");
    for(j=0;j<i-1;j++){
        printf("%d",ticketNo[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
            fprintf(fp, "%d", (int)fullName[i]);
        }

    fprintf(fp, "%d ", TotalVisitors);
    fprintf(fp, "%s ", fullName);

    struct VisitorData v1;

    if(strcmp(yesOrNo, "y") == 0){
        printf("\nPlease enter your local ID: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %s", &ID);
        // gets(ID);

        char localIDAdd[5] = "ID";

        strcat(localIDAdd, ID);

        printf("Your local ID: ");
        puts(localIDAdd);
        v1.ID = localIDAdd;
        fprintf(fp, "%s \n", localIDAdd);

    } else if (strcmp(yesOrNo, "Y") == 0){
        printf("\n\nPlease enter your local ID: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %s", &ID);
        // gets(ID);

        char localIDAdd[5] = "IC";

        strcat(localIDAdd, ID);

        printf("Your local ID: ");
        puts(localIDAdd);
        v1.ID = localIDAdd;
        fprintf(fp, "%s \n", localIDAdd);
    }else {
        printf("\n\n Please enter your passport number: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %s", &ID);
        // gets(ID);

        char localIDAdd[5] = "PASS";

        strcat(localIDAdd, ID);

        printf("Your passport number: ");
        puts(localIDAdd);
        v1.ID = localIDAdd;
        fprintf(fp, "%s \n", localIDAdd);
    }


    char serialNumber[40];
    char ticketNum;
    my_itoa(TotalVisitors, serialNumber);
    //my_itoa(ticketNo, ticketNum);
    // printf("\ntotal visitors (char): %c", serialNumber);
    v1.SrNo = serialNumber;

    //v1.ticketNo = ticketNum;
    //strcpy(v1.ticketNo, ticketNo);

    v1.Name = fullName;
    // v1.ID = ID;

    printf("\n Your ticket information is as follows: ");
    printf("\n Your serial number: ");
    puts(v1.SrNo);
    printf("\n Your full name: ");
    puts(v1.Name);
    printf("\n ID: ");
    puts(v1.ID);
    //
    // printf("\n Your ticket number: ");
    // for(int l=0;l<i-1;l++){
     //    printf("%d",v1.ticketNo[l]);
    // }
    // puts(v1.ticketNo);

     printf("\n %s %s %s %s", v1.SrNo, v1.ticketNo, v1.Name, v1.ID);

    // ticket(v1);

    //
    printf("\nVisitor's information has been updated successfully!\n"
               "\nHow would you like to proceed?"
               "\n1) Take me back to the Menu."
               "\n2) Exit the program."
                "\n Enter choice: ");

    int choice;

    scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1){
            main();
        }
        if (choice == 2){
            printf("\nThank You!\n");
            exit(0);
        }


    fclose(fp);
}

void LookupVisitor()
{
    system("cls");

    int found = 0;
    int ID =0;
    int SrNo = 0;
    char Name[30] = "";
    char fullName[30];

    struct VisitorData v1;

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Tickets.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\tFile is not opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("You have chosen to search for a visitor.");

    if (fseek(fp, 15, SEEK_SET) != 0)
    {
         fclose(fp);
         printf("\nFacing Issue");
         exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nPlease select a way to search: ");
    printf("\n1) ID.");
    printf("\n2) Name.");
    printf("\n3) Ticket number.");
    printf("\n4) Go back to main menu.");

    int choose;
    printf("\n Enter your choice = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choose);

    printf("\n\n");

    if (choose == 1)
    {
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tEnter Visitor ID to search:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%u",&ID);
    while (fread (&v1, sizeof(v1), 1, fp))
    {
        if(v1.ID == ID)
         {
             found = 1;
             break;
         }
    }
     if(found)
     {
         printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger id = %d\n",v1.ID);
         printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger name = %s\n",v1.Name);
         //printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger Address = %s\n",v1.ticketNo);
     }
    else
    {
         printf("\nThere is no Record. Please Try again.");
    }
    }
     fclose(fp);
}
    // int Name;
    // if (choose == 2){
    // printf("\n\n\t\t\tEnter Visitor name to search:");
    // fflush(stdin);
    // scanf("%s",&Name);
    // while (fread (&AddVisitor, sizeof(AddVisitor), 1, fp))
    // {
    //     if(AddVisitor.Name == Name)
    //     {
    //         found = 1;
    //         break;
    //     }
    // }
    // if(found)
    // {
    //     printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger id = %d\n",AddVisitor.ID);
    //     printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger name = %s\n",AddVisitor.Name);
    //     printf("\n\t\t\tPassenger Address = %s\n",AddVisitor.ticketNo);
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //     printf("\nThere is no Record. Please Try again.");
    //     fflush(stdin);
    // }
    // }

    // int ticketNo;

    // if (choose == 3){
    // printf("\n\n\t\t\tEnter Visitor's Ticket Number to search:");
    // fflush(stdin);
    // scanf("%u",&ticketNo);
    // while (fread (&AddVisitor, sizeof(AddVisitor), 1, fp))
    // {
    //     if(AddVisitor.ticketNo == ticketNo)
    //     {
    //         found = 1;
    //         break;
    //     }
    // }
    // if(found)
    // {
    //     printf("\nPassenger id = %d\n",AddVisitor.ID);
    //     printf("\nPassenger name = %s\n",AddVisitor.Name);
    //     printf("\nPassenger Address = %s\n",AddVisitor.ticketNo);
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //     printf("\nThere is no Record. Please Try again.");
    //     fflush(stdin);
    // }
    // }
    // else if(choose == 4){
    // main();
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //     printf("\nInvalid Input Please try again.");
    // }
//}

void DeleteVisitor(){

}

void DisplayTickets(){
    system("cls");
    /* File pointer to hold reference to our file */
    FILE * fPtr;
    char ch;


    /*
     * Open file in r (read) mode.
     * "data/file1.txt" is complete file path to read
     */
    fPtr = fopen("tickets.txt", "r");


    /* fopen() return NULL if last operation was unsuccessful */
    if(fPtr == NULL)
    {
        /* Unable to open file hence exit */
        printf("Unable to open file. File does't exist.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /* File open success message */
    printf("Reading file contents... \n\n");

    do
    {
        /* Read single character from file */
        ch = fgetc(fPtr);

        /* Print character read on console */
        putchar(ch);

    } while(ch != EOF); /* Repeat this if last read character is not EOF */

        printf("\nAbove is the list of Visitors that are ticketholders.\n"
               "\nHow would you like to proceed?"
               "\n1) Take me back to the Menu."
               "\n2) Exit the program."
                "\n Enter choice: ");
        int Next;
        scanf("%d", &Next);
        if (Next == 1){
            main();
        }
        if (Next == 2){
            printf("\nThank You!\n");
            exit(0);
        }

    /* Done with this file, close file to release resource */
    fclose(fPtr);

}



int main(void){
    system("cls");
    printf("%s", "Hello. Welcome to Farah's theme park! Please choose an option from 1-4 to select what you'd like to do.");
    printf("\n1) Add a new visitor's information.");
    printf("\n2) Look up a visitor's information.");
    printf("\n3) Delete a visitor's information.");
    printf("\n4) Display the total number of tickets sold.");
    printf("\n0) Exit");
    printf("\n Enter your choice = ");
    int choice = 0;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            addVisitor();
            break;
        case 2:
            LookupVisitor();
            break;
        case 3:
            DeleteVisitor();
            break;
        case 4:
            DisplayTickets();
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("\nThank you!\n");
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\nInvalid Input. Please try again.");
    }
    //Switch Ended
    while(choice!=0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: While this does not directly address your question (which is unclear anyways), you may want to increase the warning level of your compiler. [On godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rf1brx4Wz) GCC gave me more than ten warnings.

Comment: It would appear as if some of the content of the original question has been deleted/edited, which makes it very difficult to interpret the answers provided since then.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct VisitorData{
char *SrNo;
char *ticketNo;
char *Name;
char *ID;
};
```

Okay, so a `VisitorData` contains four pointers.

```
void LookupVisitor()
{
    // ...
    struct VisitorData v1;

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Tickets.txt","r");
    // ...
    printf("You have chosen to search for a visitor.");

    // ...

    if (choose == 1)
    {
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tEnter Visitor ID to search:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%u",&ID);
    while (fread (&v1, sizeof(v1), 1, fp))
    {
       if(v1.ID == ID)
       {
             found = 1;
             break;
       }
```

So this makes no sense. For each entry, you read in four pointers from the file (since `v1` is a `VisitorData` and a `VisitorData` is four pointers). Then you check if the pointer's value equals the entered ID.

But why would that ever happen? Look when you wrote `v1.ID` to the file:

```
    char localIDAdd[5] = "ID";
    // ...
    v1.ID = localIDAdd;
```

So when you wrote `v1.ID` to the file, it contained the address of a character array that was local to that function but no longer exists. So your comparison checks if the value the user entered for the ID is equal to the address of a character array that existed when you wrote the ID to the file but no longer exists.

You need to rethink the data you're writing to the file so that it's the actual data you want to store in the file, not pointers to chunks of memory that are about to be released and whose values have no further meaning.

Comment: Hello. First of all thank you so very much for you help. So, you are saying that i am writing the data into the pointers instead of the actual structure? Do you know how do i fix that?

Comment: char localIDAdd[5] = "ID";
    // ...
    v1.ID = localIDAdd;  was this the main issue?

Comment: @Cbeginner You are writing the structure to the file, but the structure contains pointers. So you are writing pointers to the file -- pointers to memory that you are about to release. You need to spend some time thinking about *exactly* what *bytes* you want to write to the file and checking that the file contains the correct bytes of data.